# How to cancel in-flight requests if a new request comes in?

Tags: jquery, ajax, go

I'm using Go to create an API and serve a single-page website with sidebar links that, when clicked, update the main content area in the center of the screen. The flow is:

1. Link is clicked
2. content div is emptied
3. ajax call to API endpoint depending on what link was clicked
4. append markup containing a jquery template to content div
5. apply resulting data to the template

This is working fine as long as the user waits for content to load, which is milliseconds but in the future there could be requests that take longer. If the user is able to very quickly click multiple links that would load different content such that multiple ajax requests are in-flight, then the content that is generated is not deterministic since jquery is clearing and appending markup from multiple requests. You'd see a mixture of content from the results of both requests.

I want to only handle the latest request that comes in. If the user clicks link one and then clicks link two while request one is still in flight, request one should be cancelled and only request two should be handled.

I'm thinking this should be handled on the server but not sure how to get started. Is the following the right approach?

Make a request channel to queue incoming requests with context. After queuing, check the length of the channel and if it has multiple requests, range over the channel and call each request's context cancel function except for the last one queued.

Also, the handlers are global right now so I think would also need to negotiate an ID with the client or have the client generate ID so the server knows which client requests to cancel.

Comment: You should handle this in the client.

Comment: If you have anything concurrent, "check the length of the channel" is never a correct answer. If you can't handle this in the client, this is far too broad to answer without some specifics about the handlers and server itself. In nearly all cases it's easier to just let the old requests die than try and cancel them individually.

Comment: This becomes especially complex if you have multiple users. If two users submit back-to-back and you just dump the first one, the first user won't see their own changes *or* the other user's changes - it'll look like nothing happened. This should be handled in the client.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, this will be handled in the client with something like:

```
 var currentRequest = null;    

currentRequest = jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'value=' + text,
    url: 'AJAX_URL',
    beforeSend : function()    {           
        if(currentRequest != null) {
            currentRequest.abort();
        }
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // Success
    },
    error:function(e){
      // Error
    }
});
```